# Django dynamic object listing with foreign tables (many to many case)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show all data for an object dynamically.
Though it doesn't work very well, it shows me only the keys when I'm using many to many relationships.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Web_application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.url)


class Web_vulnerability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    web_applications = models.ManyToManyField(Web_application, blank=True) #blank True : relation optional

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.description, self.name)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^list_view/([\w-]+)$', 'django_test.views.generic_list', name='generic_list'),
```

**views.py**

```
def generic_list(request, class_name):
    template_name = 'django_test/generic_list.html'
    model = apps.get_model(app_label='django_test', model_name=class_name)
    data = model.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list' : serializers.serialize( "python", data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)}
    return render(request, 'django_test/generic_list.html', context)
```

**generic_list.html**

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                {% for field_name, field_value in object_list.0.fields.items %}
                    <td>{{ field_name }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for object in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    {% for field_name, field_value in object.fields.items %}
                        <td>{{ field_value }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is the resulting HTML table I get when accessing http://domain.com/list_view/Web_vulnerability :

```
web_applications    name    description
[2L, 3L]            SQLi    Injection SQL
[1L, 3L]            XSS     Cross Site Scripting
[]                  Test    test
```

I'd like to have the web_application name instead of `[1L,2L,...]`